# How to detect when Chrome's "click-to-play" Flash blocking feature is currently active

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash

### Tracking state of Chrome's Click-to-play feature

How do you detect that a Flash plugin has been temporarily disabled, or, conversely, detect that it has been enabled due to Chrome's "click-to-play" feature?

#### Background

Chrome's new "click-to-play" feature detects plugins that are not visibly significant and pauses them. Chrome displays a "play" button over the plugin, a user may click the "play" button to activate the plugin. (reference: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xPcpRBzyPcc)

Here's a screenshot of it in action (notice white play buttons): [image: NFL.com Flash plugin disabled by default]

You can see in this screen shot that it has paused a video-player (right column). That video player has HTML5-based controls overlaying a Flash-based video player. So, there's no way for a user to click the play-button as the entire SWF is purposefully covered by HTML5-based play/pause controls.

What I need is to detect when the SWF has been paused by the "click-to-play" feature so I can disable the controls and make the SWF interactive.

#### What I've tried

1. In JavaScript - All methods exposed via `ExternalInterface` are still available though the SWF is paused. It actually responds like it's playing and does not return an error.
2. In JavaScript - Update the size of the embedded `<object>` to > 700x400px. "Click-to-play" does not pause a SWF of this size. So, I tried using `-webkit-transfor: scale(0.5)` to use CSS to scale it back to desired size. Chrome calculates the final rendered size and pauses the SWF regardless.
3. In Flash - `stage.frameRate` returns correct value (it's not set to 0 to pause the SWF for instance)

---

In writing up this question I found an answer, decided to post here anyways in case others need help with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To circumvent the Chrome click-to-play throttling, load your SWF from the same domain and protocol as your site.

---

You can use the AS3 `ThrottleEvent` to detect when the SWF has been throttled.

```
// AS3 code
import flash.events.ThrottleEvent;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

stage.addEventListener(ThrottleEvent.THROTTLE, onThrottleEvent);

private function onThrottleEvent(e:ThrottleEvent) {
    ExternalInterface.call("onThrottleEvent", e.state); // call javascript function 
}
```

You can setup an `ExternalInterface` call to keep track of this state in JavaScript, in JavaScript manage `z-index` of your SWF based on if it's throttled or not.

```
// JS Code
var IS_THROTTLED = false;

window.onThrottleEvent = function (throttleState) {
  IS_THROTTLED = (throttleState === "throttle");
}
```

Comment: The throttle event returns a state of `throttle` and a `targetFrameRate` of 10 when Chrome has paused Flash. This is the same values it returns when Flash is throttled because it is in a background tab.
So I can't seem to tell the two apart :(

Comment: You can use JavaScript to determine `window.focus / window.blur`, that will let you know if it's in a background tab

Comment: Ah interesting, we could try using the page visibility API to detect whether the page is visible, and the scroll position to determine if the flash element is visible, and if both of those are true but Flash is throttled we could assume that Chrome has paused it.

Comment: I've realised that we need to be able to detect if the Flash element has been paused within a few seconds, and if the page is in a background tab the element will always be throttled so we don't have any way to determine if it is paused or not.

Comment: But, the Flash `throttle` event  tells you if it's been paused, and `window.onfocus` and `window.onblur` tells you if the page is in a background tab. Which scenario are you having trouble detecting?

Comment: Ah, when I tried looking at the `throttle` event I was unable to tell the difference between Chrome pausing the flash element, and the tab in the background. If you are able to get it to work could you post sample code as an answer? That way I can give you the bounty!

Comment: The scenario I'm having trouble detecting is the following: The page is loaded in a background tab. How do I detect whether Chrome has paused the flash elements within it or not?

Comment: I did this quickly, it assumes you have access to recompile your SWF: https://gist.github.com/potench/77e56f7b34edbcd8c6fe

Comment: How would I use that code to tell whether Chrome has paused the flash element in a background tab? When I tried it before the Flash element always fires the throttled event when it is in a background tab, so I don't think I have any way to tell whether it has been paused or not.

Comment: If `IS_FOCUSED` is false, then your tab is in the background.

Comment: Yeah, I can tell if the tab is in the background. When a tab is in the background I can't tell whether the Flash element has been paused or not.

Comment: Hi guys, just a quick question here, do you know if there is a certain amount of time that Chrome will wait before making a swf click to play? I've been running some tests and I will usually see my swf play for a couple of seconds before firing a throttle event and becoming click-to-play. Is this time delay something that stays constant, or is more or less random?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the question, It really really shed some light on my problem. But honestly I didn't get how to solve without re-sizing the frame. I'm just playing an iframe video in a wordpress page. I cannot change the video frame size since it will crash the design down. Could you help me to employ your solution in the php wordpress page..?

Comment: @RossiMilanBob The solution I went with is to host the ".swf" file on the same domain as your webpage.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of others who are looking for the rules around Flash blocking stuff,please see them below:

- The Flash Content and the page are loaded from the same domain.
  Unknown Width and Height of the Flash Object ie when Chrome gets the
  width and height as 0 or less than 0.
- The Flash Content is
  whitelisted by the user in Chrome Settings.
- The Width and Height of
  the Flash Object are less than or equal to 5 each, considering the
  content to be Tiny and essential.
- The Width and Height of the
  Flash object are equal or greater than 398x298.
- The Aspect Ratio
  of the content is 16:9, (with an allowed deviation of 0.01) AND  the
  width*height area is at least 120K.

At least one of the above criterias need to be met, in order to get the content marked as Essential and not get Auto-Paused. Although, I have seen few deviations and Chrome hasn't made any public announcement on the rules yet.

Answer (score 2):

Add an empty Flash file larger than 398x298 at the bottom of your page. I found once you have at least one Flash file above their minimum Chrome will not pause any of your Flash. You cannot hide this extra Flash file with CSS. Optionally use a javascript timeout (3 seconds) to hide the empty Flash file in case it messes with your page layout. I'm using swfObject for embedding.