# how to auto-play in below code?

Tags: javascript, html

here i try to autoplay video but not autoplay when i using

```
 <object   data="http://swf.yowindow.com/yowidget3.swf" width="220" height="150">

        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/>
        <param name="autoplay" value="true">
        <param name="autostart" value="1" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
        <param name="flashvars" 
        value="location_id=gn:1880252&amp;location_name=Singapore&amp;landscape=airport&amp;time_format=12&amp;unit_system=custom&amp;u_temperature=c&amp;u_wind_speed=mph&amp;u_pressure=in&amp;u_pressure_level=sea&amp;u_distance=mile&amp;u_rain_rate=in&amp;background=#FFFFFF&amp;mini_action=full_screen&amp;copyright_bar=false"
    />

</object>
```

Comment: what problem you are facing now, I mean what output you are getting now?

Comment: @muhammadwaqas after click on video its play...but i want to auto-play on web load..

Comment: @HemangiSojitraguddu I can't even get your code to work! Can you create a working jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: yeah I am also not able to run this in fiddle

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't do this as it's controlled at the browser level unless you can optimize your flash object to not trigger the blocking by browser. [See related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876385)